# install phpimageeditor without Joomla/Wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, joomla, editor

I would like to use http://www.phpimageeditor.se/ on a website without joomla or wordpress - it says "it´s easy to add to your own Content Management System" in the documentation - but there's no documentation whatsoever on how to do that. All the files are full of references to joomla/wordpress-functions, so of course I get lots of errors. Is that possible at all? Or is it possible to call the Image Editor separately, once it's installed in joomla/wordpress, without using the CMS's media libraries?

Comment: Did you try the installation instructions for just the image editor, not within Joomla/WP? http://www.phpimageeditor.se/installation.php#lite

Comment: No, I didn't, because it says only the Pro version is allowed to be used in commercial projects. So you can use the Lite version separately, but not the Pro version? Still wondering: Is it possible to call the editor from outside wordpress, if I install wordpress on the same domain?